# how to close subscriber

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After rospy.Subscriber(),after a period of time or after an event this may no longer need,how to close this subscriber

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257163/how-to-close-subscriber/) by [dyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29703/dyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rospy.Subscriber gives you a [Subscriber](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html) that can be shut down by calling *.unregister()

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0